# Angular Flex boxes with connecting line

Tags: html, css, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to create a couple boxes with text inside and a line that connects them all. I created a class for each box like this:

```
.box {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

And then to create a couple boxes I have this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
   <div class="box" *ngFor="let box of boxes" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
     <div>
       {{box.firstText}}
     </div>
     <div>
        {{box.secondText}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a horizontal line that connects each box so I tried to add a `<hr>` tag at the end of the box in each loop like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
       <div class="box" *ngFor="let box of boxes" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
         <div>
           {{box.firstText}}
         </div>
         <div>
            {{box.secondText}}
         </div>
          <hr> //Addded here
       </div>
    </div>
```

But this line doesn't show up anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The `hr` doesn't show between because it is within the column layout, so it is being added at the bottom of the inside of the `.box`.

The `hr` should be a child of the `row` structure because we want it next to the boxes, but we also want it to be repeated between each box, so it must be in the `ngFor`. We can use a `ng-container` to hold the for loop (and it will be invisible in the dom, so fxLayout doesn't affect it).

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let box of boxes; let l=last">
    <div class="box" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <div>
        {{box.firstText}}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{box.secondText}}
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <hr fxFlex *ngIf="!l">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I also added  `center` to the `fxLayoutAlign` to vertically center the `hr`.

And in the `ngFor` I added `; let l=last` to be able to hide the last hr with a `ngIf`.

Here is the result:
[image: flex boxes with hr in between]
[image: flex boxes with structure showing]